# Timer control increment counter

Tags: c#, timer

So I'm trying to add a timer into my code that at every 1.5 seconds my vehCount will increase by one.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;

namespace AssignmentCA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Vehicle.vehCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    class Vehicle
        {
        public static int vehCount = 0;
        private void spawnVehicle()
            {
                Timer tm = new Timer();
                tm.Interval = 1500;
                tm.Elapsed += timerTick;
                vehCount++;
                tm.Start();
            }
            private void timerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                vehCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have never used timers before and when I run i get 0 but it never increments by 1. How can I achieve this.

Comment: Your `spawnVehicle` method is not called - timer is not created

Comment: is vehicle meant to be a static class?

Comment: make your method public and static - then call in Main.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't Totally clear to me what you want to do, but you aren't calling the spawnVehicle method at all.

Here's a solution for what you have posted. Look that spawnVehicle is called on the static constructor of the class Vehicle! In order to call spawnVehicle from a static constructor , it needs to be static as well.

```
class Vehicle
{
    static Vehicle()
    {
        spawnVehicle();
    }

    public static int vehCount = 0;
    static void spawnVehicle()
    {
        Timer tm = new Timer();
        tm.Interval = 1500;
        tm.Elapsed += (s, e) => vehCount++;
        vehCount++;
        tm.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: By accessing to vehCount, the constructor is called automatically

Comment: output to console would be nice to see whether it works.